# Image Similarity - Deep Learning vs hand-crafted features

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, neural-network, feature-extraction, deep-learning

I am doing research in the field of computer vision, and am working on a problem related to finding visually similar images to a query image. For example, finding t-shirts of similar colour with similar patterns (Striped/ Checkered), or shoes of similar colour and shape, and so on.

I have explored hand-crafted image features such as Color Histograms, Texture features, Shape features (Histogram of Oriented Gradients), SIFT and so on. I have also read up literature about Deep Neural Networks (Convolutional Neural Networks), which have been trained on massive amounts of data and are currently state of the art in Image Classification.

I was wondering if the same features (extracted from the CNN's) can also be used for my project - finding fine-grained similarities between images. From what I understand, the CNNs have learnt good representative features that can help classify images - for example, be it a red shirt or a blue shirt or an orange shirt, it is able to identify that the image is a shirt. However it doesn't understand that an orange shirt looks more similar to a red shirt than a blue shirt does, and hence it is not able to capture these similarities.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I would like to know if there are any Deep Neural Networks that capture these similarities, and have proven to be superior to the hand-crafted features. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand if this is what you mean, but CNNs are trained end-to-end as classifiers, and the features they learn are basically a byproduct of this. You wouldn't typically use a CNN simply as a feature extractor (although it's possible). But maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes, CNNs are used as classifiers. There are some pre-trained models available such as Overfeat, Caffe which have been trained on the imagenet dataset with over a million images across 1000 categories. I have read that the features extracted from the last layers  of these networks can be used to train custom classifiers (for your own dataset) and these have proved to be superior to hand-crafted features when it comes to classification  http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6382. Can these features be used for similarity computation(as per question), or do these models have to be trained differently?

Comment: Yes, that's certainly worth a try. If you have very specific needs, like your example of distinguishing orange/red shirts from blue shirts and so on, then it's possible that the CNN simply never had a need to learn these very specific features, in which case you would need to train better features for your use case. But this is hard to say without trying it.

Comment: There are many search engines that provide for users to upload an image and find similar images (for example, in the field of fashion). I understand that they may use Deep Learning to identify the contents of the images, but to actually suggest visually similar images, would they have different trained models, or would it be an image feature comparison?

Comment: Maybe they use the feature come from `fully connected layer`, and use those features to compute the feature distance.

Answer (score 1):

For your task, a CNN is definitely worth a try!

Many researchers used networks which are pretrained for Image Classification and obtained state-of-the-art results on fine-grained classification. For example, trying to classify [birds species](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2952) or cars.

Now, your task is not classification, but it is related. You can think about similarity as some geometric distance between features, which are basically vectors. Thus, you may carry out some experiments computing the distance between the feature vectors for all your training images (the reference) and the  feature vector extracted from the query image.

CNNs features extracted from the first layers of the net should be more related to color or other graphical traits, rather than more "semantical" ones.

Alternatively, there is some work on learning directly a similarity metric through CNN, see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4661) for example.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit out-dated, but it can still be useful for other people. Yes, CNNs can be used for image similarity and I used before. As Flavio pointed out, for a simple start, you can use a pre-trained CNN of your choice such as Alexnet,GoogleNet etc.. and then use it as feature extractor. You can compare the features based on the distance, similar pictures will have a smaller distance between their feature vectors.